# Repository Pattern Access Multiple Tables?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities, repository

We have recently changed the implementation from ADO.NET to Repository Pattern and generated entities using Entity Framework.

Now I am trying to access 2 tables(Accounts and Submission) and I am not getting Include method to access second table.
TO access Single table, SelectAll Method is giving all required data. WOndering what am i doing wrong here?

Appreciate your responses.

**Here is my Code:**

```
public class GPController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly IRepository<Account> _acctRepository;
        private readonly IRepository<Submission> _subRepository;

        public GPController(IRepository<Account> acctRepository, IRepository<Submission> subRepository)
        {
            _acctRepository = acctRepository;
            _subRepository = subRepository;
        }



        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult CreateAccount( Account account)
        {
            try
            {
                _acctRepository.Insert(account);
                _acctRepository.Save();
                return Ok<bool>(true);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult CreateSubmission(Submission submission)
        {
            try
            {
                _subRepository.SelectAll().ToList();
                _subRepository.Save();
                return Ok<bool>(true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult GetAccountTreeDetails()
        {
            try
            {
                var accounts = _acctRepository.SelectAll().ToList();
                var submissions = _subRepository.SelectAll().ToList();
                //if (submissions.Any())
                //{
                //    var data = from a in accounts
                //               left join s in submissions on a.AccountId equals s.AccountId  
                //               select a; 
                //}

                //var data = from acct in _acctRepository
                //                join sub in _subRepository on acct.AccountId equals sub.AccountId
                //                select acct;


                return Ok<List<Account>>(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here AccountTable is the Primary table that has AccountID.
WhereAs Submission Table has AccountID that is Foreign Keyed from Account Table.

**Here is the Account Table:** 
[image]

**Here is the Submission Table:**
[image]

Comment: What's the relationship between Accounts and submissions - 1-n, 1-1...

Comment: Account table is the Primary table that has AccountID. Whereas Submissions table has AccountID that is Foriegn key referenced from Accounts table.

Comment: I am assuming that you are trying to fix GetAccountTreeDetails(). What is it that you are trying to retrieve - all submissions related to an Account or all accounts and related submissions?? BTW CreateSubmission() method does not seem to do anything - I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 1):

Your SelectAll() should be something like this:

```
var accounts = _acctRepository.SelectAll().Include(a=> a.Submissions).ToList();
```

Make sure that SelectAll() returns a queryable.
Secondly, your models should have navigation properties, like below:

```
public class Account
    {
        public virtual ICollection<Submission> Submissions { get; set; }
    }

public class Submission
{
    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
}
```